# WoWLAN under Linux 3.1 with N-1030

Tags: linux, wlan

Linux 3.1 has added support for WoWLAN, and as far as I understand my card Intel Centrino N-1030 supports WoWLAN. However, ethtool for eth0 gives info:

```
# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 10Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x000020c6 (8390)
                   probe link rx_err tx_err hw
    Link detected: no
```

And:

```
# ethtool wlan0
Settings for wlan0:
    Link detected: yes
```

So, my question is, how to check that WoWLAN is enabled on the card, and how do I send a magic packet to a wireless interface. I googled https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=WoWLAN+linux+3.1+how+to+ and some other similar strings but I don't see the actual command ... Thanks, in advance. Oz